# AABB of a sphere's screen space projection

Tags: mathematics, aabb

What is a nice, neat way to get the AABB of a sphere's projection onto the screen? This is to determine simplified geometry for lights in deferred shading.

Comment: Axis Alighned Bounding Box... So you want a box around the sphere??

Comment: I want to know what screen space rectangle to draw that will touch all of the pixels a specified sphere would touch.

Comment: Have you searched google for AABB of a sphere space projection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the correct derivation of the extents on [AltDevBlogADay](http://www.massimpressionsprojects.com/dev/altdevblog/2012/03/01/getting-the-projected-extent-of-a-sphere-to-the-near-plane/).

Comment: Link's dead :/ Don't suppose there's a copy elsewhere?

Comment: Found a copy! http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/164007/Indepth_Getting_the_projected_extent_of_a_sphere_to_the_near_plane.php @ZorbaTHut

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but here's my version (GLSL):

```
/// <summary>
/// returns the screen-space (normalized device coordinates) bounds of a projected sphere
/// </summary>
/// <param name="center">view-space center of the sphere</param>
/// <param name="radius">world or view space radius of the sphere</param>
/// <param name="boxMin">minimum (bottom left) projected bounds</param>
/// <param name="boxMax">maximum (top right) projected bounds</param>
bool GetProjectedBounds(vec3 center, float radius, inout vec3 boxMin, inout vec3 boxMax)
{

    /// frustum culling helper
    if (ShouldCull(center,radius))
        return false;


    float d2 = dot(center,center);

    float a = sqrt(d2 - radius * radius);

    /// view-aligned "right" vector (right angle to the view plane from the center of the sphere. Since  "up" is always (0,n,0), replaced cross product with vec3(-c.z, 0, c.x)
    vec3 right = (radius / a) * vec3(-center.z, 0, center.x);
    vec3 up = vec3(0,radius,0);

    vec4 projectedRight  = Projection * vec4(right,0);
    vec4 projectedUp     = Projection * vec4(up,0);

    vec4 projectedCenter = Projection * vec4(center,1);

    vec4 north  = projectedCenter + projectedUp;
    vec4 east   = projectedCenter + projectedRight;
    vec4 south  = projectedCenter - projectedUp;
    vec4 west   = projectedCenter - projectedRight;

    north /= north.w ;
    east  /= east.w  ;
    west  /= west.w  ;
    south /= south.w ;

    boxMin = min(min(min(east,west),north),south).xyz;
    boxMax = max(max(max(east,west),north),south).xyz;


    return true;
}
```

The version I'm using performs frustum culling at the beginning (view space).

And, here's the output (my visualizer adds some padding on the right and left):

[image: screen-space AABB of a sphere]

The yellow represents the undistorted bounds of the sphere. Note that the left and right half-widths (relative to the real center of the sphere, at the center of the yellow circle) are different lengths.